# Batch File that analyze and present data from csv files

Tags: csv, batch-file

I want to create a .bat file that will present the last row of every .csv files that the file name start with "Togo".
The batch file will be located in the same folder as the .csv files.
To output should be the:
[File Name]
[Last Row Data]

This batch file should always run and test the .csv files every 5 minutes.

Comment: Try asking a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm a beginner and don't know were to start, this is not the response I was looking for...

Answer (score 1):

SO is not a free code-writing service. Your question is likely to be deleted or closed since you have not shown any attempt to solve your problem.

That having been said, it's difficult to start in batch, so here's a solution.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\togo*.csv" '
) DO (
 FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%q IN ("%sourcedir%\%%a") DO SET "line=%%q"
 ECHO %%a !line!
)

GOTO :EOF
```

The first two lines turn off batch's debugging display (show-the-command, then execute it) and invoke a mode where access to variables that have changed within a "code block" (parenthesised series of commands) is enabled (normally, it's disabled and only the value at the time the `if` (or whatever) is encountered is available.)

Line 3 sets a variable called `sourcedir` and assigns it a value. The enclosing quotes ensure that trailing spaces are not included in the value assigned. I've deliberately used a directoryname that includes spaces because that's a common problem and it proves the batch in my test regime. Your directoryname would be different - simply substitute that. The directoryname <kbd>.</kbd> means "the current directory"

Lines 4-6 could be combined to one - just stylistics. It means "perform a directory scan, no directory names (`/a-d`) in basic form (`/b`) that is, names-only, of the directory whose name is in the variable `sourcedir` and whose names fit the pattern `togo*.csv`. Process each resultant line by ignoring the default delimiters and assigning the result (ie the entire line of the directory list, ie the filenames) to the metavariable (loop-control variable) `%%a`.

The next line reads each line of the file built from the source-directory name and the filename currently in `%%a`. `delims` is set to *nothing* so the entire line will be assigned to the metavariable `%%q` and the `usebackq` option tells `cmd` that the parenthesised string is a quoted-filename, not a string (or a single-quoted command-to-be-executed as in the first `for`.) the variable `line` will then be set with each successive line from the file, so `;ine` will have the last line from the file when the `for...%%q...` ends.

The following line show the filename in `%%a` and the text from the last line of that file in `line`.

Note the difference - `%%x` to access the contents of a metavariable, `%var%` to access the contents of a variable, but `!var!` to access the changed value (if `delayedexpansion` has been invoked).

The `goto :eof` means "go to the physical end-of-file" `CMD` understands `:eof` to mean "physical end-of-file"

So - cut-and-paste to a file named *whatever*.bat and then run by simply entering

```
*whatever*
```

In general,

```
for /?
```

will yield help for the `for` command, and this holds for most batch commands. Look on SO for thousands of examples.

You may also examine

```
timeout
cls
choice
```

for clues about how to achieve your `every 5 minutes` ambition. You might want to run this from the task scheduler to get an `every 5 minutes` display - many ways to achieve the same thing.